# При загрузки сайта c локального на хостинг не прогрузились css и js

Tags: wordpress

Сделал сайт, на через wp сделал базу данных, пытаюсь залить на хостинг, ошибок нет но не прогружается css и js, а только структура. Хотя на локальном все работает и база данных правильно скачана. Что может быть? Вот сам сайт https://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Да у вас там https без сертификата, браузер не пускает. Вы с этого начните.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас сайт работает по https протоколу, а css и скрипты подгружается по http протоколу. Браузер такой блокирует.

Решение: либо укажите https

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='https://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='maincss-css'  href='https://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/wp-content/themes/test/assets/css/style.css?ver=5.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/wp-content/themes/test/assets/js/script.js?ver=1' id='script-js'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://p87856.hostru07.fornex.host/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
```

либо вообще не указывайте протокол и домен

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='maincss-css'  href='/wp-content/themes/test/assets/css/style.css?ver=5.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/themes/test/assets/js/script.js?ver=1' id='script-js'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хотел бы еще узнать, может вы сможете подсказать. Когда делал сайт на wordpress, то для картинок использовал путь вот такой: http://localhost:8888/test/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/reference.png, и сейчас у меня они отображаются только у меня. А те фотки, которые делал через <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?> то не открываются даже у меня

Comment: @Павел Я не знаком с wordpress. А вы не забудьте отметить ответ как верный